# How can I get the index of an element from a loop, sourced from a numpy array?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, matrix

I have a matrix (shown below), and I loop over the elements of the matrix with the followng code.

```
for column in m:
    for elem in column:
        ...
```

How can I get the index of `elem` in the matrix? I've heard of `np.where()` but I've refrained from using it because of how it returns a list and I'd have to get the index of the elemet in the list in order to get the index of the element in the matrix. Is there an alternative solution to get the index of `elem` in the matrix, such as `.index()` is used for lists?

Example matrix:

```
[[0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 1 2 1 1 2 2 1 0]
 [0 1 0 2 2 0 2 0 0]
 [0 2 0 2 1 1 0 2 0]
 [0 2 2 2 2 0 1 2 0]
 [0 1 1 2 1 0 0 1 0]
 [0 2 2 1 1 1 2 1 0]
 [0 1 2 0 0 2 2 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]]
```

Comment: Have you read about using `enumerate` when iterating? (basic Python).

Comment: range of array shape ?

Comment: @hpaulj I've read about using `enumerate` but how would it work with this? Would it be something like `for i, value in enumerate(column):`? What would `i` look like here?

Comment: Why dont you keep track of index by yourself? Since you're not sure how to use enumerate.

Comment: @lionrocker221 Why don't you try it and see what i looks like?  The documentation is pretty clear and it's easy to see if you print it

Comment: @HamzaHathoute what do you mean? I'm trying to find the index of the element specified in the loop.

Comment: @lionrocker221 you could use two variables, i and j and increment them when needed. Definitely not clean so I highly suggest you see how enumerate works.

Comment: @lionrocker221 What is it that you are trying to do? generally speaking, looping over numpy arrays are bad ideas and not the point of using an array. Maybe a bit more explanation and we can help replace the loop entirely.

Comment: @Ehsan I'm trying to loop over the array and get the 8 neighboring elements of each element.

Comment: @lionrocker221 8 neighboring element as in 4 above and 4 below in the same column? You can do it much easier without loop. And what are you intending to do with those elements?

Comment: @Ehsan I mean one in 8 directions. I'm going to switch the elements based on a set of rules. Like if there's a 1 next to a 2, turn the 1 into a 2 and turn the 2 into a 0.

Answer (score 0):

If you enumerate over the rows and columns you will get the indices. If you just want the elements, you already have them in `elem`. For example:

```
m = np.array([
 [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
 [0, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 0],
 [0, 1, 0, 2, 2, 0, 2, 0, 0],
 [0, 2, 0, 2, 1, 1, 0, 2, 0],
 [0, 2, 2, 2, 2, 0, 1, 2, 0],
 [0, 1, 1, 2, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0],
 [0, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 0],
 [0, 1, 2, 0, 0, 2, 2, 0, 0],
 [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]])

for i_row, row in enumerate(m):
    for i_col, elem in enumerate(row):
        # here m[i_row][i_col] == elem
        print(i_row, i_col)
```

Prints:

```
0 0
0 1
0 2
0 3
0 4
0 5
0 6
etc..
```

Answer (score 0):

From OP's comment on the post:

```
from skimage.util.shape import view_as_windows
print(view_as_windows(a, (3,3)))
```

output:

```
[[[[0 0 0]
   [0 1 2]
   [0 1 0]]

  [[0 0 0]
   [1 2 1]
   [1 0 2]]

  [[0 0 0]
   [2 1 1]
   [0 2 2]]

  [[0 0 0]
   [1 1 2]
   [2 2 0]]

  [[0 0 0]
   [1 2 2]
   [2 0 2]]
  ...
```

Comment: @lionrocker221 Please see the edit on my post. If this is not what you are looking for, a simple input/output example will help better. Thank you.